# How to share all drives through iis, I mean sharing all my drive letters

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I wanna know a way of share all my drivers or my computer root path through iss, not just a letter, in order to see in all my network computers

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct is that you really should not do this, but the answer is to create IIS virtual directories to each of your volumes as part of the default website. it will in effect create a shortcut to each drive from c:\inetpub\www.

Note that this will not correctly serve all file types to a browser. Web servers have content handlers specific to normal web content like xml, html, txt, etc. The site and the browser will choose to display some of the files rather than download them to the host as a byte stream by default.

Overall this is not what IIS is for, so you won't be able to get it to work flawlessly without some more specialized software.